# Excel Formula for different font color in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you provide a formula to display a single cell value as text with multiple colors in Excel, where half of the text is red and the remaining text is blue, as the value is given in a single cell and needs to be displayed in two colors within the same cell.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpnoA.png)

**Formula:**

```
="ERRORS ("& COUNTIF(D17:D,"=Fail") &") & WARNINGS ("& COUNTIF(D17:D,"=Pass") &")"
```

**Output**

`ERRORS (5) & WARNINGS (5)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYBsb.png)

Comment: I don't think its possible to change the color of a cell based on the formula in excel. Maybe remove the excel tag?

Answer (score 2):

The "multiple colors" concept you describe is called *rich text*. In Google Sheets, rich text cannot be produced with any spreadsheet formula. To programmatically put rich text in in a cell, you need a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info). See [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder).